# Python: unable to break out of while loop called as a daemon thread

Tags: python, while-loop, kivy

I need the while loop `while counter < 100` to loop until the counter reaches 100, or until an external condition `self.stop_loop == True` is met. The class `alarm_ring()` is called as a daemon thread as it must run in the background until `alarm_time = alarm_current_instance.get_alarm_time()`.
I want `self.stop_loop` to be activated by the class `on_press` (which is called by a Kivy button), however, the while loop `while counter < 100` does not seem to detect when the Boolean state of `self.stop_loop` is altered and therefore continues looping. How can I make the while loop break when `self.stop_loop` is set to `True` by the function `on_press`?

Here's the relevant sections of my Python code:

```
def on_press_set(self):
        self.ids.alarm_set.source = "AlarmSetButton_darker.png"
        alarm = Alarm()
        self.alarm_thread = threading.Thread(target=alarm.alarm_ring, args=(),daemon=True)  # initialises an instance of Thread. As 'daemon = True', this thread will run in the background until the program terminates (or until it finishes running).
        self.alarm_thread.start()

class Alarm(Screen):
    def alarm_ring(self):
        alarm_current_instance = App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('alarmdisplay')
        alarm_time = alarm_current_instance.get_alarm_time()
        print(alarm_time)
        while True:
            if alarm_time == time.strftime("%H:%M"):
                self.stop_loop = False
                self.alarm_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.alarm_audio, args=(),daemon=True)  # initialises an instance of Thread. As 'daemon = True', this thread will run in the background until the program terminates (or until it finishes running).
                self.alarm_thread.start()
                self.alarm_image()
                break
    def alarm_image(self):
        alarm_ring_current_instance = App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('alarmring')
        counter = 0
        while counter < 100:
            counter += 1
            if self.stop_loop == True:
                App.get_running_app().root.current = "timedisplay"
                break
            App.get_running_app().root.current = "alarmring"
            alarm_ring_current_instance.ids.Baldwin.opacity = 1
            time.sleep(0.5)
            alarm_ring_current_instance.ids.Baldwin.opacity = 0
            time.sleep(0.5)
        App.get_running_app().root.current = "timedisplay"

    def on_press(self):
        osascript.osascript("set volume output volume 0")
        self.stop_loop = True

    def alarm_audio(self):
        counter = 0
        while counter < 25:
            counter +=1
            sound = AudioSegment.from_wav('AlarmAudio.wav')
            play(sound)
        osascript.osascript("set volume output volume 100")
```

Here's the section of the kv file which calls `on_press` (`time display` is the name of another window in the Kv file):

```
<Alarm>
    name: "alarmring"

    FloatLayout:

        Button:
            id: Baldwin_button
            opacity: 0
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
            size_hint: (0.25,0.6)
            on_press:
                root.on_press()
                root.manager.current = "timedisplay"
```

Comment: How are you calling `on_press()` can you show that part

Comment: I have edited the original post to show the Kv file.

Comment: see I don't know kivy, but I think I know the problem, do you see this line `alarm = Alarm()` this is where you create an instance of Alarm class. this `alarm` variable is supposed to be used while calling `on_press`. As every instance has its own set of `self.` variables, if `on_press` is called by a different instance than `alarm` it sure won't make any changes to `self.stop_loop`

Comment: Thanks! I changed alarm = Alarm() to alarm = App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('alarmring') and that fixed it.